# Use text-overflow: ellipsis on an anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor, css

How can you make a `<a>` tag use the `text-overflow: ellipsis` property? I have long link names that I would like to truncate.

Here is my attempt using the usual text-overflow approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wg8N/

Comment: Solved it. 

You can't text-overflow an anchor tag. So wrap your text in `<p>` tags, and apply the overflow to those tags. I'll post the answer when SO allows it

Comment: You can use it on an anchor tag if you change it to display: block or inline-block.  The problem isn't the tag, it's the fact that it's display: inline.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You'll need to change it to `display: block;` or something else like `inline-block` and specify a width, e.g:

```
a {
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```